# How to create items control derivative with such separators?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, prism

This is design I need to implement

[image]

Basically, this is menu items separated with vertical bar.
I'm using PRISM and whole bar is basically `ItemsControl` where I inject menu items

I wonder if it's possible to style (without writing code) ItemsControl in such a way that it will automatically insert bar after all items except last one?

It wouldn't be a big deal if I didn't want to skip last vertical bar.

Important! I can't just insert separator manually because menu items inserted from different modules (PRISM) and I never know which one is the last one, so I need to solve this problem on container level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a Clip and RectangleGeometry. By inserting the pipe at the left of your data template, Set a Rectangle Clip to Trim off the first pipe. A little hacky and you may have to fudge the Clip start to get it to look right, but here's a working sample:

```
<ItemsControl xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String>No</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Pipe</sys:String>
    <sys:String>On</sys:String>
    <sys:String>First</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item</sys:String>
    <ItemsControl.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="5,0,1000,10000" />
    </ItemsControl.Clip>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="|" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the vertical bar in the ItemsTemplate in your ItemsControl.

Comment: But it will be for every item. And I need it between items

Comment: Just put it on the right (or left) end of the template. terphi gave an example.